# Do you think that such a badge "is needed"/"would need"?

Tags: grammaticality

1) Do you think that such a badge is needed?

2) Do you think that such a badge would need?

According to you, is 2) proper English?

Comment: Can you provide some more context for the question? In what situation would you say this sentence?

Comment: My first reaction (to #2): *Would need what?!*

Answer (score 1):

Correcting your second sentence, the two mean different things.

> Do you think that such a badge is needed?

You are asking if you need a badge for something that is happening or will soon happen.

> Do you think that such a badge would be needed?

You are asking if you need a badge for something that might happen.